# python how to compare elements in a dictionary?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python dictionary like :

```
pydict =  {"group1":[{"name":"john","count":1},{"name":"johny","count":2}],
           "group2":[{"name":"raj","count":1},{"name":"johny","count":4}],
           "group3":[{"name":"ram","count":1},{"name":"raj","count":4}]
}
```

I want to iterate through pydict and i want to maintain a table like below:

```
Name   group1   group2   group3
johny   true    true
raj     true    true
```

I tried using python **sets** so the each keys elements in pydict can be assigned to sets and finally do intersection but it is not helping.

Please suggest me a fastest way to do this.

Comment: What does the `true` represent?

Comment: its just a indication. It means that Name present in that group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really naive implementation of this would be to just make another `dict` based on names:

```
from collections import defaultdict
names = defaultdict(set)    
for group in sorted(pydict.keys()):
    for person in pydict[group]:
        names[person["name"]].add(group)

for key, val in names.iteritems():
    print key, ":", list(val)
```

Output

> johny : ['group1', 'group2']
>
> john : ['group1']
>
> raj : ['group3', 'group2']
>
> ram : ['group3']

Comment: This assumes that the presence of that name implies `count > 0`